# VBScript and multilevel OLE?

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word, ole

I have made a vbscript to target some computers and do wmi queries on them, and my boss wants this data to be put inside a document. The problem is that this document is a Microsoft Word document with embedded excel objects inside it. Now I have searched wide and far on google on any way to target and manipulate an object inside and object with OLE, but I seem to be getting nowhere.

So my question to you is if someone has some code for this I could look over or maybe a tutorial, and quite possible even tell me if it is even possible?

Comment: You wish to update an Excel file embedded in a Word doc yesno? Why not update the Excel file itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes based on the chart being an embedded Excel object, as first stated.

```
''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213725(office.11).aspx
''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174298(office.11).aspx

    Dim wd ''As Word.Applicatio
    Dim shs ''As InlineShapes
    Dim objChart ''As Excel.Chart
    Dim objSheet ''As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objOLE ''As Excel.Workbook
    Dim NewSrs ''As Series

    Set wd=CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wd.Documents.Open "C:\Docs\Doc1.docm"
    wd.Visible=True


    Set shs = wd.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    ''Just the one shape in this example
    shs(1).OLEFormat.Activate

    ''The OLE Object contained
    Set objOLE = shs(1).OLEFormat.Object

    ''The chart and worksheet
    Set objChart = objOLE.Charts("chart1")
    Set objSheet = objOLE.Worksheets("sheet1")

    objSheet.Range("e1") = "NewData"
    objSheet.Range("e2") = 11
    objSheet.Range("e3") = 12

    Set NewSrs = objChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With NewSrs
        .Name = "=Sheet1!e1"
        .Values = "=Sheet1!e2:e3"
    End With
```

Notes for MS Graph

```
''VBA: Reference: Microsoft Graph x.x Object Library
''Graph Object Model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198537(office.10).aspx

Dim shs ''As InlineShapes
Dim objDS ''As Graph.DataSheet
Dim objOLE ''As Graph.Chart

    Set shs = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

    ''The OLE Object contained
    shs(3).OLEFormat.Activate
    Set objOLE = shs(3).OLEFormat.Object
    Set objDS = objOLE.Application.DataSheet

    ''00=Corners, Row titles = 01,02 ...
    ''Column titles = A0, B0 ...
    ''Cells = A1, B1 ... E9 ...
    objDS.Range("E0") = "New"
    objDS.Range("E1") = 11
    objDS.Range("E2") = 12
    objDS.Range("E3") = 9

Set objDS = Nothing
Set objOLE = Nothing
Set shs = Nothing
```

Comment: Using objOLE, you need only consider VBA as it applies to Excel, so, for example, you can say variously: `objOLE.Charts.Count` or `Set objChart = objOLE.Charts(1)` or `ChartName = objOLE.Charts(1).Name`  Exactly the same thing can be done with worksheets.

Comment: Is the object contained an Excel chart object or an MS Chart object?

Comment: You can try `objOLE.Application` and/or `shs(1).OLEFormat.ClassType` to get information.

Comment: It is not Excel it is MS Graph Chart, the notes are for Excel. I will see what I can do.

Comment: [shs(1).Application.DataSheet.Range("a1").Value = "75"]
That bit of code right there updates the values of the datasheet. :)
Link to the msdn article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190239

Comment: You beat me to posting. I wanted a complete piece :)

Comment: I actually have another problem, I can't seem to be able to choose anything but the first instance of datasheets in the document?

Comment: How are you choosing the datasheet and how many are there? I thought MS Graph had one datasheet per chart? Do you mean a different inlineshape?

Comment: Yeah, I think I might have figured it out, I forgot to activate the different inlineshapes, doh. :P