# How to programatically (using VBA) to modify the charts in Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2007

Folks,

I would like to write a VBA macro to modify the charts in a Word document but I don't know how ? I used the old school trick below with no hope:

- Select a Chart in an open document
- Start Macro Recording
- Modify the chart
- Stop Recording
- Edit the macro

The surprise here is that the macro is empty !!

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some useful information in this related question: [VBScript and multilevel OLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735218/vbs-and-multilevel-ole/2739242#2739242)