# Modify an embedded Excel object inside a Word doc

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word, ole

I need example code or even a 3rd party object that will allow me to get to an excel object embedded in a word doc. I have already tried Aspose and they do not have the capabilities yet. Has anyone done it or do you know of a 3rd party object that will?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i did it! I appreciate the link posted by Remou. It did provide some support after I got past the initial hurdle...

Here is my code:

```
        WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Report.docx")
        Dim iOLE As Int16
        Dim oSheet As Object
        Dim oOLE As Object
        For iOLE = 1 To WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.ShapeRange.Count 'These are the embedded objects
            If Not WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.ShapeRange(iOLE).OLEFormat Is Nothing Then '- make sure it is OLE
                If WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.ShapeRange(iOLE).OLEFormat.ProgID.Contains("Excel") Then '- make sure it's an Excel object
                    '- I have found an Excel Object!!!
                    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.ShapeRange(iOLE).OLEFormat.Activate()
                    oOLE = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.ShapeRange(iOLE).OLEFormat.Object
                    oSheet = oOLE.Worksheets(1) '- I can assert that each of them has at least one sheet and that I need the first one...
                    oSheet.Range("BB3") = "I did it!" '- setting some text to verify I made it in...

                End If

            End If

        Next

        WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("c:\temp\report_test.docx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find some information here: [VBScript and multilevel OLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735218/vbs-and-multilevel-ole/2739242#2739242)

Comment: Ah man, that looked promising... when I check the InlineShapes on my ActiveDocument, the count is zero (0). I'll keep playing around with this. Thanks for the suggestion.