# Edit Excel Spreadsheet object in word document (C# Interop)

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I am currently trying to edit cells of an excel spreadsheet object with c# interop. I inserted it in a word document as an object.

Until there i didn't succeed to programm anything that really works. I'm able to select the component but i can't open it to edition and then reach grid's cells.

I use a button control in a custom office ribbon to launch edit. Here is my method:

```
public void EditTable(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Word.Application oWordApp = (Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        Word.Document oWordDoc = oWordApp.ActiveDocument;

        Word.Bookmark ReqsBookmark = DocumentHelper.GetBookmark("test");

        ReqsBookmark.Select();
    }
```

The only way i know to access a specific object with interop is with bookmarks.

Does anybody have an idea of how doing such a thing?

Comment: Enter the code snippets tried by yourself. Let us know the exact requirement and we can help you. Always narrow down the question. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

In Word, an Excel worksheet (workbook) is "wrapped" in an OLE control that is a member of the `InlineShapes` or `Shapes` collection. So you need the `AddOLEObject` method of the collection you want to use.

Access to the object model of the OLE server (Excel) is through the `OLEFormat` property of the `InlineShape` or `Shape`. So your code would be something like the sample below.

Note that although you say this is a VSTO project, the code you show us is not VSTO. You're starting up a new instance of the Word.Application, but the VSTO Add-in would be running in-process. My code is VSTO code, but can certainly be adjusted for other situations...

```
{
    Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.app.ActiveDocument;
    object oRngTarget = Globals.ThisAddIn.app.Selection.Range;
    //object oRngTarget = DocumentHelper.GetBookmark("test").Range;
    object oOLEClass = "Excel.Sheet.12";
    object oFalse = false;
    Word.InlineShape ils = doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref oOLEClass, ref missing, ref missing, 
                               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oRngTarget);
    Word.OLEFormat olef = ils.OLEFormat;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo  oldCI= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)olef.Object;
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    try
    {
        ws.get_Range("A1").Value2 = "New category";
        ws.get_Range("B1").Value2 = 6.8;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        ws = null;
        wb = null;
        ils = null;
        doc = null;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
    }
}
```

To later work with a spreadsheet in the Word document, you basically follow the same principle: declare and instantiate a `InlineShape.OLEFormat` object, Activate it, then cast `olef.Object` to an Excel.Workbook:

```
olef.Activate();
Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)olef.Object;
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded thanks to this post about [modify an embedded Excel object inside a Word doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109033/modify-an-embedded-excel-object-inside-a-word-doc)

Here's the c# method if anybody need it one day:

```
    {
        Word.Document oWordDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Excel.Workbook oOLE = null;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet = null;

        Word.InlineShapes ils = oWordDoc.InlineShapes;

        ils[1].OLEFormat.Activate();
        oOLE = ils[1].OLEFormat.Object;

        oSheet = oOLE.Worksheets[1];
        oSheet.get_Range("A1").Value = "I did it too!";
    }
```

Thank you again @CindyMeister for your answer, it helped me to understand how it really works.