# How do I read Excel embedded in a Word document using Interop with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, embedded-resource, excel-interop

I am trying to read an Excel sheet embedded in a Word document. What do I do after opening the Word document? These are the references I am using (Excel,Word)-- are there any others I need to use?

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

Word.Application wordApp;
Word.Document wordDoc;
Word.Range wordRange;

public TestCase Test()
{
   wordApp = new Word.Application();
   wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"document");

   what next??
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit Excel Spreadsheet object in word document (C# Interop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272419/edit-excel-spreadsheet-object-in-word-document-c-interop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with the embedded worksheet, it's necessary to `Activate` it.

Once it's *activated*, you can handle the `Excel.Workbook`, `Excel.Application` and `Excel.Worksheet` and `Excel.Range` objects:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range xlRange;

        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"c:\debug\word-excel.docm");

        // activate the object before you can interact with it
        wordDoc.InlineShapes[1].OLEFormat.Activate();

        xlWorkBook = wordDoc.InlineShapes[1].OLEFormat.Object;
        xlApp = xlWorkBook.Parent;
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
        xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:D10"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Embedded documents are represented by inline shapes in the document, so you can access them in the following way:

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim num as Integer
    Dim AD as document
    Set AD = activedocument

    Dim numObjects As Integer
    numObjects = AD.InlineShapes.count

    MsgBox numObjects  ' prints "11"

    For num = 1 To numObjects    
        If AD.InlineShapes(num).Type = 1 Then
            'it's an embedded OLE type so open it.            
            AD.InlineShapes(num).OLEFormat.Open
        End If
    Next num
End Sub
```