# How do I get files that are attached to a word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to access Word documents through c#. Some of the Word documents have objects inside them. This is the equivalent of email attachments.

To insert some file in a Word document in Word 2007, you go to Insert -> Object -> Object... and select some file.

My question is, how do I get the file out using C#?

Here is an example of how it is done with an email using Outlook:

```
    protected Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass outlookApplication = null;
    protected Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem        mailItem           = null;
    protected Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace        mapi               = null;

public OutlookFileExtracter(string filename, string contentPrefix, int startAttachmentNumber)
    this.outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    this.mapi = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    mailItem = mapi.OpenSharedItem(filename) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem;
}

public Collection<string> GetFileNames()
{
    String extension;
    if (this.fileNamesOrig == null)
    {
        int numberOfFiles = this.mailItem.Attachments.Count;

        this.fileNamesOrig = new Collection<string>();
        this.fileNamesDest = new Collection<string>();
        this.fileValidBools = new Collection<bool>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
        {
            //First attachment number is 1
            fileNamesOrig.Add(this.mailItem.Attachments[i + 1].FileName);
            this.fileValidBools.Add(false);
        }

        for (int la = 0; la < numberOfFiles; la++)
        {
            extension = Path.GetExtension(fileNamesOrig[la]).ToUpper().Trim('.');
            this.fileNamesDest.Add(this.contentPrefix + (this.startAttachmentNumber + la) + "." + extension);
        }
    }
    return this.fileNamesOrig;
}
```

Apparently the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word doesn't use attachments, but then I don't know what it is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you have a unusual set-up, Word objects are nothing like Outlook attachments. This post is VBScript, but it may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735218/vbs-and-multilevel-ole/2739242#2739242

Comment: +1 on the post remou mentions. that's exactly what you'll need to do to retrieve embedded OLE objects in a Word doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be referring to OLE, which is heavily used in Office documents. From the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding

> Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) is a technology developed by Microsoft that allows embedding and linking to documents and other objects. For developers, it brought OLE Control eXtension (OCX), a way to develop and use custom user interface elements. On a technical level, an OLE object is any object that implements the IOleObject interface, possibly along with a wide range of other interfaces, depending on the object's needs.

That website will initially look to be unrelated to your question, however, It's what is being used.

If you want to skip the meat, scroll right down to the bottom where you'll find an 'external link' to: http://www.pldaniels.com/ripole/

> ripOLE is a small program/library designed to pull out attachments from OLE2 data files (ie, MS Office documents). ripOLE is BSD licenced meaning that commercial projects can also use the code without worry of licence costs or legal liabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) classes to read the data. A Word 2007 file is just a zip file, so the objects you're after are probably inside in a format you can read.

There's a collection of articles on MSDN titled "Word 2007 Visual How Tos" that might be of some use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537324(v=office.12).aspx

You can read about the Open XML Format SDK here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As said by Arafangion they are OLE objects, for most of them if you know what they are you could ask them to export their content somewhere else see [Extract embedded document with the word document](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/85ef2249-0344-42f5-8dec-e7c09f98c62b/) for other you may need to extract the binary content and hope that your user could find an application to read it.